# Как в Spring Boot в методе контроллера использовать Map<Key, Value>?

Tags: spring-boot, rest

В [официальной документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.10/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) по Spring Boot Web MVC сказано, что:

> Когда аннотация `@RequestParam` объявляется как `Map<String, String>` или `MultiValueMap<String, String>` без имени параметра, указанного в аннотации, `Map` заполняется значениями параметра запроса для каждого заданного имени параметра.

В общем виде `GET` метод контроллера, принимающий `Map` будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```java
@GetMapping
public Set<Employee> findAll(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
    // ... some code here ....
}
```

Всем известно, что при создании `REST API` рекомендуется придерживаться общепринятых стандартов в области маппинга HTTP запросов, поэтому метод, который будет получать все объекты, например найти всех сотрудников, должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```java
@GetMapping
public Set<Employee> findAll() {
    return service.findAll();
}
```

Тогда вопрос. Почему при добавлении вышеперечисленных методов одновременно в контроллере будет вызывать исключение:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'ApplicationController' method com.some-company.prj.controller.ApplicationController#findAll(Map)
```

Как этого избежать? Мне нужно 2 метода в контроллере:

1. Который выводи список всех сотрудников
2. Который принимает в себя GET запрос вида `?ключ=значение&ключ=значение`:

```
http://localhost:8080/employees?sort_by=name&order_by=ASC&sort_by=department&order_by=DESC
```

**Что я предпринимал**

Можно оставить один метод, который принимает в себя `Map` и внутри уже проверять `Map` на `null`:

````java
```java
@GetMapping
public Set<Employee> findAll(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
    if(params == null) {
        return service.findAll();
    } else {
        return service.findAll(params);
    }
}
````

Comment: Нужно объявить этот параметр опциональным. По твоей же ссылке "By default, method parameters that use this annotation are required, but you can specify that a method parameter is optional by setting the @RequestParam annotation’s required flag to false or by declaring the argument with an java.util.Optional wrapper."

Comment: Напишите ответ, я приму.